# What to do when someone deletes the correct answer to your question?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

Here's my question:  [Is this possibly an impossible MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4229647/262056)

As you can see I've updated the question with details about the deleted answer.  I'm pretty sure that the answerer deleted the answer thinking it was incorrect because I told them in the comments that it wasn't working properly.

I'd like to give this person credit for the answer, even if their answer didn't contain the missing condition (I bet it did, and I just missed it).  If it wasn't for their guidance I never would have solved my problem.

What's the proper protocol in this situation?  I suppose what I've done is best, but maybe there is another avenue I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your best option in this case would be to flag your own question for `Moderator Attention` and request to undelete the answer (with a short explanation why). The Moderator should be able to see that answer and get in touch with the User to clarify the situation.

Though, I don't know of any protocol in such situations (never heard of or seen before either) and if the mods really want to do such things.

Comment: They can also just undelete the answer, which is probably what they'll do

Comment: @Michael: Yes, but I'm not sure if they'd do it without approval of the author.

Comment: It's possible to undelete without approval, but there have been many heated discussions raised about doing that.

Comment: This is what I did, and a moderator undeleted the answer.  I was then able to accept it.  Thank, Bobby.

Answer (score 0):

I think they (a moderator) should undelete the answer and disassociate it from the author, that way there's no reason for it to be deleted.

Comment: What if he deleted it because he believed it would be wrong (or not helpful)? In that case he wouldn't get the rep from accepting the answer (and maybe further upvotes), although he answered the question.

Comment: @Bobby:  I'm pretty sure you are correct in your assumption.  I told him his solution did not work for me.  In fact, I was either wrong (due to not implementing the answer correctly) *OR* it was very, very close to being correct, and without this answer I would not have been able to solve the problem.

Comment: They don't have the ability to do that anyway, a dev would have to handle it